# Create a single object for query result

Tags: php, oop

I've three models (representation of database table) which basically has setter and getter methods. I've a service class which has action methods. In one of the service class method, I'm writing a query which join two tables. I want to know how to create a single object for the query result.

For example:

I've two model files m1.php and m2.php

m1.php

```
class M1Model {
  public $id;
  public $name;

  public function setM1ID($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function setM1Name($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function getM1ID() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getM1Name() {
    $this->name;
  }
}
```

m2.php

```
class M2Model {

  public $id;
  public $cat_name;
  public $m1_id;

  public function setM2ID($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function setM2CatName($cat_name) {
    $this->cat_name = $cat_name;
  }

  public function setM1ID($m1_id) {
    $this->m1_id = $m1_id;
  }

  public function getM2ID() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getM2CatName() {
    return $this->cat_name;
  }

  public function getM1ID() {
    return $this->m1_id;
  }
}
```

service.php

```
include m1.php;
include m2.php;

class DataService {

  function __construct() {
    $m1 = new M1Model();
    $m2 = new M2Model();
  }

  function getAllData() {
    $query = "database query using join";
    //Here I want to return object (Not generic object)
    return $object;
  }
}
```

From getAllData(), I want to return single object and non generic object. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the result of your query using [`PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_object()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

See PHP documentation:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->NAME;
```

Comment: Edd, Thanks for your reply. The solution you provided gives me the generic object, but I do not want generic object. I want service object

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a DataService object you could put your $query inside DataService constructor...